# How to access gmail and read the content of the email using UFT

Tags: hp-uft

After I complete an order, system will send a temp password to gmail account. It will take about 20 minutes for the email to be sent. Then I will have to read the email content and get the temp password.

Example:

1. Script clicks submit button.
2. wait 20 minutes
3. Access gmail and look for the email coming from xyz company.
4. If email arrived, parse the temp password to a  variable.

Sample email:

> Email subject: Your temp pw
>
> Email body:
>
> Dear sdfsf sdfsdf,
>
> Thank you for registering for the nnn.
>
> Your temporary password is: Drhh5JT
>
> Your temporary password to log in, https://examplesite.com/, and then reset
> your password.
>
> Your temporary password will expire in 4 hours.
>
> If you have questions, call us at 666-666-6666
>
> Thank you, The xyz

How can I accomplish this using UFT?

Answer (score 0):

Once you navigate to your required email and open it. You need to copy Frame source in a Notepad file *(this can be achieved by right click > Select "View Frame Source")*

once it is copied as text file you can simply use `FileSystemObject` to read it and search for 'Temporary Password' and retrieve it.

Alternatively you can add this mail account in MS Outlook and use `Outlook.application` for achieving the same.

Comment: How will I navigate to the specific email?  I can wait 20 minutes. After 20 minutes, how can I instruct UFT to find that specific email and then store the email content into a text file? After that, I can search for the password.

Comment: Are you using Mail App like outlook or the browser ?